# Android Studio turn my files into gibberish. Cannot load settings from file warrning

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Files gets turned red on the project tree structure, when opening them they turn into gibberish, Undo or revert does not work.

Portion of my  XML and Java files turned red, when opening them i had the privilege to see my source code like that:

```
    �PNG


    IHDR           �s�  IDATx^�1��0E_B�6    W�.�-�Q�a�i�H�"b{6!�DNl�-�++��ߑgԷ��"URD�%�ڰ��і���㎡�
    ��pg�������ˍ5P�5���BC=�h���W�
    ���/��O8��Ιp��U��^']�ԱO��ۏ�Y��
    ����Ox�w
    m���L��v��_/vI��M��O��]R8:E0��<^��>�) �����L UZ39,v�X�{�s�@�i�C5����YI��    IEND�B`�
```

*Cannot Load settings from file* warrning is being displayed.

Files gets restored to the original after deleting the following folders and restarting:

> C:\Users\user_name\.android

and

> C:\Users\user_name\.android_studio3.4

Answer (score -1):

This is a PNG file. You've potentially got filesystem/disk corruption problems.

Comment: It was XML file like a moment ago... something is happening specifically with Android studio, The reason i know? reinstalling fixed it last time..

Comment: Doesn't seems like disk corruption. It's most definitely Android Studio.